# add object to nsmutable array model

Tags: arrays, object, model, nsmutablearray, addition

I have a nsmutable array and this is it's content:

```
Longitude, Latitude, Name, Town
```

this 4 entries are 14 times in my array.

my problem is, that i cannot add "Distance" to my array.

please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can only add objects to an NSMutableArray, not e.g. floats. So if "Distance" is a class, and you instantiated it, you can add the instance using the addObject: method.

Comment: "Distance is a variable and I put it into a string.

Comment: So, it it is an NSString object sss, and you can add it to an NSMutableArray xxx using [xxx addObject:sss], but maybe I don't understand your problem.